# After Azure WebApp integration to VNET - Unable to connect to Azure SQL

Tags: azure, web-applications, integration, vnet

I was trying to connect my Azure webapp(paas) to my VM in another VNET - I could get this working by doing a VNET integration following the instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

I could now connect to the VMs in the destination VNET however the Webapp is now unable to connect with the Azure SQL(PaaS) .  Is it not that webapp should continue to access the PaaS resources as before or do I need to update any configuration to get this connectivity.

Edit: I was able to get this working with a VPN(Route based) and with a VPN GW and P2S connection.
However for some reason I do not get this working with my existing VPN which is also a route based but has a Azure SSL VPN SSTP. Can this cause some connection issue to Azure SQL ?

Appreciate your response

PS: I do not want to use ASE specifically as the need is very limited and cost for going to ASE is high for this use case.

Comment: did you integrate it (sql paas) with the vnet?

Comment: No, the Azure SQL (PaaS) is not integrated with VNET. Is that needed ? Is it not supposed to be connected by the WebApp through Internet itself ?

Comment: By the way, I also tried connecting the Azure SQL (PaaS) to the same VNET using the Azure SQL Firewall setting->Virtual Network. But I could not still connect with this